# Decomposing Distance Matrix D for approximating Original Matrix A

Tags: distance, matrix-decomposition

Let's say we have a matrix $A \in R^{n \times d}$  where n is the number of elements and d is the dimension size. And we calculate the pairwise distances between each elements; say cosine for instance which results $D \in R^{n \times n}$ matrix, in addition it is square and symmetric.

Is there any way to decompose this distance/similarity matrix $D$ so that it can be converted/approximated back to its original matrix $A$ ?

Comment: If you use euclidean distance, you can reconstruct your cloud points from the pairwise distances, up to an isometry (i.e translation, rotation etc...) if the matrix verify the Schoenberg criterion.

Comment: This is called [Multidimensional scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_scaling)

Comment: @J.Delaney Thank you very much!  I read the initial section of wiki page and noticed that the theoretical father of Functional Data Analysis is the same as MDS. So, is MDS related with FDA ?